# Bootstrap 4 Dashboard's active item not displayed in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sticky

In the following url https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/ you can find a Dashboard template using latest Bootstrap 4.

In Chrome, navbar items are displayed properly and specifically active navbar item with the name **Dashboard** (can not embed image due to lack of reputation to visualize the issue) while in Firefox the active **Dashboard** element is not displayed at all!

I am using the template in a project and can not figure out what causes this issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Firefox lack of support for `position: sticky` which is used in the sidebar. As a workaround, you can use `position: absolute` on the sidebar...

```
.sidebar-sticky {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 Dashboard Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/GWeYrLhUd0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did know that detail.

Comment: I updated the answer, `position: absolute;` works better in all browsers in this case.

Comment: For me it works better with relative because I am using Bootstrap 4 in an Angular 5 project and the routerActiveLink does not occupy the whole width of the sidebar using position as absolute. I have set the background-color property instead of color on the active route link.